# ShrinkWrap deforms second eye

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, shrinkwrap

Having the left eye shrinkwrapped on a sphere it looks just fine. However the right eye is being stretched to the right. Perfectionist as I am they have to look exactly the same. I cannot find the reason why and also adding a simpledeform doesn't seem to help. And if someone knows a workflow to get the eyes looking like this [image: this] that would be perfect!
The workflow I had planned right now is:

1. Combining two circles and join them together as an eye with a pupil.
2. Wrap the eye(s) around the body (sphere)
3. Cut out the eyes by boolean operation
4. Solidify the body (spehere)

[image: Blendfile]

Blendfile can be found [here](https://pasteall.org/media/a/8/a8ec6127444d5eaaac4a6eb43f48f0b6.blend).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing exactly what it's being told to do. If you view along the Y axis `CTRL-numpad 1` and hit `numpad 5` for orthographic view, you'll see the 2 eyes are not centered on the ghost in the direction that shrinkwrap is projecting it.
[image]

As you have it, in Project mode, Shrinkwrap projects a mesh into another mesh along a defined axis.

The simplest fix, is to move both eyes to be centered across the centre line of the ghost.
[image]

Also, apply your rotation so the direction of projection makes more sense, Negative Y.

Comment: Great for this lead. The origin point being centered across the centre line of the ghost did the trick! Now it is symmetrical again as your picture.